# Need to time & date stamp in Google sheets but reflect four hours earlier

Tags: date, time, google-sheets, datetimeoffset

I have a column in Google Sheets that when I enter initials, the script time stamps into the next column which then, through existing cell formulas of varying values (example: =B9-Time(4,4,0) ) reflects several other offset simulated timestamps.

The problem I am now having is that any subsequent entries must be in real time and stamped as such which prevents me from using a timezone trick to do it. Basically, I just need the script to show a current time stamp minus four hours (this is for my "set-up" cell which automates a backfill of simulated times) but function normally for all future entries (this is for a medication administration simulation if understanding the purpose helps clarify my question).

Here is my working script (minus the ability to subtract four hours from current):

```
if( x.getName() == "Vitals" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet 
  var y = x.getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i used to test. You can pull out the hours adjustment part.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  x=e.source.getSheetName()
  if( x == "Vitals" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet 
   var y = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var d = new Date();// d is now a date object
       var h=d.getHours()
       var m=d.getMinutes()
       var s=d.getSeconds()
       var nh=h-4 //subtract 4 hrs
       d.setHours(nh,m,s,0); //set the new hours , min Secs and milliSecs as well
       nextCell.setValue(d);
    }
  } 
}
```

Below is a link to my shared test spreadsheet. Make a copy and try it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sMcd0ivy_LE8kkCto264ETjzMubRniWcdFYzYoh-Cj8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you be able to direct me how to insert it into the right place? Another gentleman told me I had to assign these event triggers to the respective column/cell because they will not run in the script editor. When I erase the VITALS section of my script and add this one to my first cell in my "initials" column (column 1) as the calibration value under conditional fotmatting -> custom formula, nothing happens in the offset box (column 2). Thanks again!

Comment: I have added a link to my test spreadsheet to the answer. If this doesn't answer your question, share your spreadsheet and I will take a look.

Comment: Go to your script editor. Put your cursor at the end of the last line of the onOpen function (line 19). Enter and a new line will new created. Copy and paste the above code there. Save and you should be good to go. Below is a link to a copy of your spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0hnOS4NWWQOjocSNAge3T7k2ItZktBvZ37jXyCdcbo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems like when I enter the timestamp in the golden empty box of initials, it stamps the current time in column B of the Vitals instead of four hours prior...is it doing that on your end?

Comment: OK I see the problem. I didn't know you already had another onEdit. You can't have two. If I comment out your onEdit mine works correctly. Do you need the MAR date time to also offset 4 hrs? I can do that too. Let me know. I am going to be away a few hours. I will check when I get back.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, that would be GREAT...all of the entries are backfill-automatic all based on the vitals (golden) box...is it possible to auto-backfill on the MAR sheet all from that single golden box entry that I'd like to calibrate the form with? That gives our students a realistic starting point for the day in their lab with a quick and easy modification throughout the form, and a simple reset/time change as we need to. The overall goal is to be compliant with electronic utilization without having to have the students pay extra for outside database access at about $200/semester

Comment: @Paul SO does not like these conversations to get too long. You can reach me at ednelson@sbcglobal.net. I will be happy to solve this for you. I can do what you do now with MAR, but I don't understand the auto-backfill on the MAR sheet.